# Bringing UITextField to the top in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have  UITextField in a UITableViewCell. When I click on it, the keyboard obscures it. I have tries but it does not work:

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[self tableView] scrollRectToVisible:[textField frame] animated:YES];
}
```

How can I avoid the keyboard hiding the textfield by bringing the textfield up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{
CGPoint pnt = [tblView convertPoint:textField.bounds.origin fromView:textField];
path = [[tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pnt] retain];
[tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
return YES;
}
```

For return

```
 -(IBAction)Done:(id)sender
{
[tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
[tvDetail resignFirstResponder];

}
```

You have to set content inset of tableviw set to 200 in tableview property in xib.

Answer (score 0):

`[textField frame]` contains the location of the textfield inside the table cell, not inside the table itself. You need a way to compute the area of where the `textField` is in the table, or it might be better to use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` instead. (when setting up the table cells you can set its `textField.tag=indexPath.row` to make this easier).

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As what babbidi suggested, `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` is a good point. Also, you may change the frame of your tableView or its super view simultaneously. You can register to default notification center with `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and  `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, and arrange your animation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem (using a different logic)- With this, the screen should move up when the Keyboard shows up.

Implement this.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 40; // or choose a number based on your cell height. 
}
```

Comment: And set the footer view as a blank view so that it blends with the App.

Comment: Hi, just tried this and it does not work. Any ideas why it's not working.

Comment: Use a value of 100. Return 100 ; ?